# Narrow down a union produced with template literal type based on passed values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a union type which is a result of a template literal type containing two other string union types. It contains all possible permutations of the values as expected. The template literal type is constructed based on generic types on a function, which takes a tuple. Is it possible to narrow the union based on the values passed to that function, so that only the combinations determined by the tuple are present?
Hard to explain, so here's a simple code snippet:

```
function get<T extends string, K extends string>(vals: [T, K][]) {
  type FullKey = `${T}${K}`
  const answer: FullKey[] = []

  for(const v of vals) {
    const fullKey: FullKey = `${v[0]}${v[1]}`
    answer.push(fullKey)
  }

  return answer
}

const answer = get([['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b']])
//     ^?
// How to make this ('1a' | '2b')[] instead?
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=45&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQDwBVGoB5SpgAmAzoqVAE4xjIA0iA0rgUWRdbcgHwAUANwCGAG1IAuRAG0sjJgF0p8gJSIA3gChEiKAE8ADqkQAxECJFNUuxAF5EAAwAkarAF9nTV-a2IICSohCYKQA7qhUkqbmlrpKttLyGj7AcFR8fsFQiAKIcMDZoqSqmtraGQGg0VaRZhZW8U5qAlIADPLuTVIAjO3epYHBYVQAdPogpAAWfJV1uso%20rknaVOggVEhBoeEaixrlWZtD8WhQfFJSAORdF4wXQhfyjJcATDeIFwBGDyoaAPS--UQAD0APx-AEACTgIR0cEQAFshABrIxQCYwch8K73RAAH3ezy%20yjitEoqCExBBQA)

I looked at Distributive Conditional Types, that seem like maybe could be the solution here, but I don't know how to apply them here.

Comment: You could mimic what your code is doing like this: https://tsplay.dev/Nar9Pm

Comment: pekala does that work for you? @caTS, would you write up an answer if so?

Comment: @caTS pretty slick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to mingle our complex types with the implementation, let's move all of that outside into the return type:

```
// actual type magic happens outside of the implementation
function get<A extends [T, K][], T extends string, K extends string>(vals: [...A]): { [K in keyof A]: `${A[K][0]}${A[K][1]}` }[number][];
function get(vals: string[][]) {
  const answer: string[] = [] // now just string[]

  for(const v of vals) {
    const fullKey = `${v[0]}${v[1]}` // who CARES that this is just a plain string
    answer.push(fullKey)
  }

  return answer // string[]
}
```

We use another type parameter `A`, and infer `vals` as a tuple. Then in the return type we can "map" over the tuple to create the desired result.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXq6LN)

Comment: A slight tweak that removes the need for a function overload definition, note the use of `as const`: https://tsplay.dev/m36ZqN

Comment: Certainly interesting but I always prefer to move the types outside - they tend to get in the way and make the implementation harder to read.

Comment: alright I give, is there a name for the pattern or structure of `[...T]` as opposed to `[T]`? I can't track it down in the documentation, and Google has not been fruitful. It somehow seems related or equivalent to an `as const` declaration for collapsing a more general type down to its specific/literal type value. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @jered [Variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)